# Passing variable data to QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have a qt application with different widgets. All widgets should use the same data, so I declare a fixed list of classes for this data (different data from different events). The active data got selected with a QComboBox.
This data get passed as an reference to one widget, which contains a QtPlot with a QAbstractTableModel to visualize the data.

mainwindow.h:

```
MyClass currentData;
QList<MyClass> dataList;
plotWidgetPointer* plotWidget;
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget* parent ) : QMainWindow( parent )
{
    plotWidgetPointer = new plotWidget( currentData, this );
}

void MaindWindow::selectionChange(int index)
{
    if( index != -1)
    {
        currentData = dataList.at( index );
    }
}
```

plotWidget.h:

```
public: 
   explicit plotWidget(MyClass& myClass, QWidget* parent = 0);
```

plotWidget.cpp:

```
plotWidget::plotWidget(MyClass& myClass, QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}
```

After starting the programm and switching the data over the combobox the application crashes. Does anybody know why?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `dataList.count() >= MainWindow::ui::combo::itemsCount()`?

Comment: The way you constructed "datalist" may give us some clue